# Link interaction of multiple volumes in xtk

Tags: xtk

If I have two 3D volumes rendered, how would I link the two volumes so that interaction with one will result in the same reaction in the other?

Answer (score 0):

you can propagate the renderer1.camera.view to renderer2.camera.view. Both are Float32Arrays and hold the camera matrices.